# Pandas - Make some headers row values

Tags: python, pandas, transpose

I have what I assume might be a complexed ask.

I have a few columns in my dataframe, for each date column I want to store the date headers in the column called "Dates" and then I want to create 2 new columns to store the max and min values

DataFrame

**DataFrame**

| ID | Item | DateMade_Min | DateMade_Max | DelDate_Min | DelDate_Max | ExpDate_Min | ExpDate_Max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2322 | 01/01/2020 | 01/01/2020 | 05/06/2020 | 07/06/2020 | 06/05/2022 | 09/09/2022 |
| 2 | 4454 | 03/04/2020 | 01/01/2021 | 07/08/2020 | 31/08/2020 | 15/12/2022 | 09/01/2023 |

**Desired Output**

| ID | Item | Dates | Min | Max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2322 | DateMade | 01/01/2020 | 01/01/2020 |
| 1 | 2322 | DelDate | 05/06/2020 | 07/06/2020 |
| 1 | 2322 | ExpDate | 06/05/2022 | 09/09/2022 |
| 2 | 4454 | DateMade | 03/04/2020 | 01/01/2021 |
| 2 | 4454 | DelDate | 07/08/2020 | 31/08/2020 |
| 2 | 4454 | ExpDate | 15/12/2022 | 09/01/2023 |

Answer (score 2):

You can reshape with an intermediate stacking and a MultiIndex:

```
out = (df
   .set_index(['ID', 'Item'])
   .pipe(lambda d: d.set_axis(d.columns.str.split('_', expand=True), axis=1))
   .stack(0)
   .reset_index().rename(columns={'level_2': 'Dates'})
)
```

output:

```
   ID  Item     Dates         Max         Min
0   1  2322  DateMade  01/01/2020  01/01/2020
1   1  2322   DelDate  07/06/2020  05/06/2020
2   1  2322   ExpDate  09/09/2022  06/05/2022
3   2  4454  DateMade  01/01/2021  03/04/2020
4   2  4454   DelDate  31/08/2020  07/08/2020
5   2  4454   ExpDate  09/01/2023  15/12/2022
```

###### alternative

Alternatively, you can use the [`janitor`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) helper module and its [`pivot_longer`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) function:

```
# pip install janitor
import janitor

out = df.pivot_longer(
    index=['ID', 'Item'], 
    names_to=('Dates', '.value'), 
    names_sep = '_', 
    sort_by_appearance=True
)
```

Comment: super thank you, I must take a look into this and the inner workings, looks very efficient

Comment: @mozeay , if I want to index just the ID column will the code stay the same?, it doesn't seem to be working correctly for me

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to doit

```
# melt the DF 
df2=df.melt(['ID','Item'])

# split the date field on '_' to form two columns

df2[['date','minmax']]=df2['variable'].str.split('_', expand=True)

# use pivot to reformat the resultset
df2.pivot(index=['ID','Item','date'], columns='minmax', values='value').reset_index()
```

```
minmax  ID  Item    date    Max     Min
0   1   2322    DateMade    01/01/2020  01/01/2020
1   1   2322    DelDate     07/06/2020  05/06/2020
2   1   2322    ExpDate     09/09/2022  06/05/2022
3   2   4454    DateMade    01/01/2021  03/04/2020
4   2   4454    DelDate     31/08/2020  07/08/2020
5   2   4454    ExpDate     09/01/2023  15/12/2022
```

Comment: If I just want to melt on the TF columns what changes would I need to make as I'm getting an error **ValueError: Columns must be same length as key**